# Why circus server is not getting start/stop?

Tags: python, circusd

I am using circus server to run python program as a daemon process. But now circus is not getting started or stop or not even the status of the circus i get to know.

I tried with the :

```
sudo circusctl restart <name_of_repository>
sudo circusctl stop
sudo circusctl start
sudo circusctl status
```

But all the commands gives me following error :

```
Timed out. Try to raise the --timeout value
```

should anyone know about this error. Please help me thanks in advance..

Comment: could you provide sample of your circus.ini file?

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar issue when launching circus with this command:

```
bin/circusd --daemon
```

Cirsusd didn't start ( ps ax | grep circus ) gave nothing. But no error was rised.  And

```
bin/circusctl status
```

gave me response

```
Timed out.
A time out usually happens in one of those cases:
#1 The Circus daemon could not be reached.
#2 The Circus daemon took too long to perform the operation
For #1, make sure you are hitting the right place
by checking your --endpoint option.
For #2, if you are not expecting a result to
come back, increase your timeout option value
(particularly with waiting switches)
```

Which means circusctl couldn't communicate with circus. I have had a lot of headache, but then simply started circusd without --daemon argument, like this:

```
bin/circusd
```

And circus now gave me real error:

```
backports.configparser.InterpolationSyntaxError: '%' must be followed by '%' or '(', found: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

This errror was quickly fixed by double % in buildout config files.

So the real problem was circusd didn't give any errors when was launched with --daemon argument.